# Submit button not working. No action is taken when i click on the create account button

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is the form on whic i'm working. i want it to send the data to 1.php but when i click on the create account button. please tell what is wrong with this code.

```
<div class="logmod__form">
  <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="1.php" class="simform" method="post">
    <div class="sminputs">
      <div class="input full">
        <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sminputs">
      <div class="input string optional">
        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="text" size="50" />
      </div>
      <div class="input string optional">
        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="simform__actions">
      <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Create Account" />
      <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms & Privacy</a></span> </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo `type="sumbit"`

Answer (score 2):

Correct it in your button

```
type="submit"
```

You missed `name` Attribute in your fields without it nothing is submitted

```
<input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50"  name="user-pw-repeat"/>
```